# Can I eager load attributes from one-to-one relationship for delegation without instantiating the related model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delegates, eager-loading

Imagine this:

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :ground

  delegate :elevation_in_meters, to: :ground

  # attributes: stories, roof_type
end

class Ground < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :house

  # attributes: elevation_in_meters, geo_data
end
```

Then to eager load ground so that `house.elevation_in_meters` can be called without loading `Ground` I can do:

```
houses=House.includes(:ground).first(3)
```

The problem with this is, that the entire `Ground` object is actually instantiated with all attributes including the `geo_data` attribute - which I don't need in this case. The reason why I care is, that the query needs to be VERY performant, and `geo_data` is a pretty huge text field. I only need to read the delegated attributes, not write to them.

What approach could I take on eager loading the `elevation_in_meters` attribute from `Ground` without loading everything from `Ground`?

I'm on rails 4.1 btw

NOTE: Preferably I would like to have this eager loading behaviour by default for `House`, so that I do not need to specify it every time.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Do you hit a memory limit on your app? Is it too slow? How do you know that you need to limit data loading?

Comment: Because I know my needs/load and I know my current schema pretty well

Comment: You are worried by a huge text field, what is a huge text field? 1kB or 1 GB?. I would advise you to do it without worrying about perfs, and if it is too slow, use profiling and monitoring tools to determine your bottleneck.

Comment: The example is simplified. In reality there is several fields on "Ground" that I don't need in the context of a house - in fact most of them. It's not only that some are large, it's also that some are even serialized and stored as postgresql JSON - which is quite heavy lifting for rails

Comment: Try `House.includes(:ground).first(3).collect{|c| c.elevation_in_meters}`

Comment: That will eager load all ground associations, instantiate them together with all attributes, that's exactly what I don't want :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off write a scope for the model you want to partially get and select the fields you like. Notice that I used the full name (with table name) and a string for the select. I'm not sure if you could just `select(:elevation_in_meters,:geo_data)` since I've copied this from our production example, and we use some joins with this scope that wont work without the table name. Just try it yourself.

```
class Ground < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :house

  attributes: elevation_in_meters, geo_data
  scope :reduced, -> {
     select('grounds.elevation_in_meters, grounds.geo_data')
  }

end
```

With the scope present you can make a second belongs_to relation (don't be scared that it messes up your first one, since rails relations are basically just methods that are created for you), that calls the scope on your `Ground` model.

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :ground
  belongs_to :ground_reduced, ->(_o) { reduced },
    class_name: 'Ground', foreign_key: 'ground_id'

  delegate :elevation_in_meters, to: :ground_reduced 
  # go for an additional delegation if 
  # you also need this with the full object sometimes

end
```

In the end you can just call your query like this:

```
houses = House.includes(:ground_reduced).first(3)
```

Technically it is not the proper answer to your question, since the `Ground` object is still instantiated. But the instance will only have the data you wanted and the other fields will be nil, so it should do the trick.

UPDATE: 
As I just saw that you want to preferably have this behaviour as default, just add a scope for your House:

```
scope :reduced, -> { includes(:ground_reduced) }
```

You could then add this as your default scope, since your original relation will be untouched by this.

Comment: Thanks, well written :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while but I just stumbled across this.

If you're only interested in the singular attribute you can also use a `joins` combined with a `select` and the attribute will magically be added to your House instance.

```
res = House.joins(:ground).select('houses.*, grounds.elevation_in_meters').first

res.elevation_in_meters # attribute is available on the object
```

To always have this attribute present, make it the `default_scope` for `House`, like so:

```
default_scope { joins(:ground).select('houses.*, grounds.elevation_in_meters') }
```

Depending on the nature of the tables you're joining you may need a `distinct` also.